# Bit reader fails on consecutive non-multiple of 8 reads

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've been struggling with this for the last two days, and I've probably fixed at least 20 different bugs at this point.

Basically the bug is if you call ReadBits() and request anything that's not a multiple of 8, it'll work the first time, but if you call it again, with another non-multiple of 8, it won't.

I used 61 bits the first time and 33 the second just for example.

Here's the output from requesting 61 bits: 0x1FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
and from 33: 0x1FFFFFFF8

the last byte in the 33 bit output should be FF, but it's F8 for some reason? and if I were to shift it over the 3 empty bits, it would only be 30 bits long, not 33 like it should be.

```
struct BitIO {
    FILE                           *InputFP;
    fpos_t                     *InputOffset;
    uint64_t                    InputFPSize;
    uint8_t  InputBuffer[BufferSizeInBytes];
    uint64_t                  InputBitIndex;
} BitIO;

static const uint8_t ByteMask[2][8] = {
    {0xFF, 0x7F, 0x3F, 0x1F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01},
    {0xFF, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFC, 0xFE}
};

static const uint8_t ShiftTable[8] = {
    0, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
};


uint64_t Bits2Bytes(uint64_t Bits) {
    return (Bits + 7) >> 3;
};

uint64_t ReadBits(int8_t Bits2Read) {
    uint64_t OutputData = 0;

    uint64_t StartByte      = Bits2Bytes(BitIO.InputBitIndex - (BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8));
    uint64_t EndByte        = Bits2Bytes((BitIO.InputBitIndex + Bits2Read));
    uint64_t BufferShift    = ShiftTable[BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8];
    uint64_t Bits2ReadShift = ShiftTable[Bits2Read % 8];
    uint64_t ByteMaskStart  = ByteMask[0][~(BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8)];

    for (uint64_t Byte = StartByte; Byte < EndByte; Byte++) {
        if (EndByte == StartByte + 1) {
            OutputData +=  BitIO.InputBuffer[Byte] & ByteMask[1][(BitIO.InputBitIndex + Bits2Read) % 8];
            OutputData >>= ShiftTable[(BitIO.InputBitIndex + Bits2Read) % 8];
        } else if (Byte == StartByte) {
            OutputData +=  BitIO.InputBuffer[Byte] & ByteMask[1][Bits2Read % 8];
            OutputData >>= Bits2ReadShift;
            OutputData <<= 8;
        } else if (Byte == EndByte - 1) {
            OutputData +=  BitIO.InputBuffer[Byte] & ByteMask[1][(BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8)];
        } else if (Byte != StartByte && Byte != EndByte) {
            OutputData +=  BitIO.InputBuffer[Byte];
            OutputData <<= 8;
        }
    }
    BitIO.InputBitIndex += Bits2Read;
    return OutputData;
};
```

Comment: Have you stepped through it with a debugger? That should help you determine which of the variables is getting set wrong during the second call.

Comment: Can you show some sample input, the expected output, and the output you're actually getting? That may also shed some light.

Comment: I have, that's how I got it to this semi-usable state.

I'm thinking one of the tables is wrong, or is being used incorrectly, but I honestly have no idea where to begin with that, I've tweaked them a few times already, and It feels like I'm chasing my tail tbh.

Comment: `(Bits + 7) >> 3` is subject to overflow.  Suggest `(Bits >> 3) + (Bits & 7 + 7) >> 3);` or something like that.

Comment: It messes up during the (Byte == EndByte - 1) loop, It's got to be the mask, but I don't see what part is wrong, and how to change it without breaking the rest of it.

Well InputBuffer[] is 4096 bytes, and each byte is 0xFF for testing purposes.

Comment: I set it to 0xFF so I could see that the bits were all aligned properly, so if I set ReadBits to 24, I'd know if it needed to be shifted, and during which stage, etc.

Comment: You never use `ByteMaskStart`, and the loop never uses `ByteMask[0]`. So you're not starting at the right place in the first byte of the loop.

Comment: `uint64_t ByteMaskStart  = ByteMask[0][~(BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8)];` will access out of bounds. The second dimension of `ByteMask` is only 8, but `~(BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8)` is a huge number, `UINT64_MAX` or close to it

Comment: Something is wrong with `ByteMask[2][8]` and your usage of it. `ByteMask[0][..]` is only used to set `ByteMaskStart` which is not used at all. If the bit patterns are supposed to be masks for `anding` and `orring` individual bits, they are wrong. But if they are supposed to be a pair of masks to isolate an 8-bit value that spans two storage bytes, then `ByteMask[1][0]` initialised to `0xFF` is wrong: it should be `0x00`, since `ByteMask[0][0]` is also initialised to `0xFF`. And perhaps you even need a **`ByteMask[2][9]`** array, with the last element in each of the pair as `0x00` and `0xFF`.

Comment: The first loop, the (EndByte == StartByte + 1) one, is for <= 8 bit requests, that don't fall on byte boundaries. I have to have a special case for that or it won't work.

Comment: @M.M I wasn't aware of that? My intention with the negation was to reverse the bitmask because otherwise it was backwards.

Comment: I'll try that @WeatherVane, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @WeatherVane the problem with a 9 element mask, is x modulo 8 will only go from 0-7, so the 8th element will never be reached.

Comment: Here's the million dollar question: Exactly what is the routine _supposed to do_? You're expecting us to guess the spec from bad code. Not a very productive way to get an answer.

Comment: It's supposed to read from InputBuffer, and hand out the number of bits requested when the function is called.

If you read 4 bits the first time, then BitIO.InputBitIndex will be set to 4, so the next time it's called, it will mask out those 4 bits that have already been given out. That's the general purpose, to hand out X number of bits, while making sure none of the ones that have already been written out get written out again.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

The end loop `(Byte == EndByte - 1)` was masking, when it should have only been shifting `ShiftTable[(BitIO.InputBitIndex + Bits2Read) % 8]`

Now I just need to test and make sure it works for every single edge case.

Comment: Except now 64 bits only returns 59.

Comment: @MarcusJ `~0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` is `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`

Comment: I tested it with ~31, and it flipped it from 0001 1111 to 1110 0000, which is what I needed at the time, although you do have a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static const uint8_t ByteMask[2][8] = {
    {0xFF, 0x7F, 0x3F, 0x1F, 0x0F, 0x07, 0x03, 0x01},
    {0x00, 0x80, 0xC0, 0xE0, 0xF0, 0xF8, 0xFC, 0xFE}
};
```

The first entry was wrong, although the following doesn't use it.

```
// assume 0 <= n <= 64
uint64_t ReadBits (int n)
{
    uint64_t r = 0;
    uint64_t byte = BitIO.InputBitIndex / 8;
    uint64_t bit = BitIO.InputBitIndex % 8;
    while (n > 0) {
        int count = (n >= 8) ? 8 : n;
        n -= count;
        uint64_t tmp;
        // We make sure not to look at two bytes if we don't have to
        // to avoid a buffer overrun.
        if (bit == 0) {
            tmp = BitIO.InputBuffer[byte];
        }
        else {
            uint64_t x = BitIO.InputBuffer[byte] & ByteMask[0][bit];
            uint64_t y = BitIO.InputBuffer[byte + 1] & ByteMask[1][bit];
            tmp = ((x << 8) | y) >> (8 - bit);
        }
        tmp >>= (8 - count);
        BitIO.InputBitIndex += count;
        byte++;
        r = (r << count) | tmp;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: It only works for bytes though, I named it ReadBits2 to compare it, and for reading 7 bits my ReadBits returns 0x7F, and your ReadBits (aka ReadBits2) returns 0xFF.

Here's a screenshot of what Xcode produces: http://imgur.com/6Dd1KHM

Comment: Actually I rewrote it to read individual bits each loop, and it's now just 7 lines long :D